# "Do you..." questions -- a FAQ addition suggestion

Tags: discussion, faq-suggestion

I'd like to add the following to the **What kind of questions should I not ask here?** section of the [FAQ](https://photo.stackexchange.com/faq):

> If your question is in the form "Do
>   you ______?", it will tend towards
>   discussion and personal opinion, which
>   doesn't fit the site well. Try to
>   rephrase your question in a way which
>   will encourage objective,
>   comprehensive answers.
>
> Of course, "How do you..." is a different story, since it generally means "How can *I*...", and those questions are usually just right.

Maybe there could be an example: "Do you use sharpening technique X?" could be "What are the pros and cons of sharpening technique X?"

Exact wording open to change, of course. There could be something about how "Do you know..." probably is the start of a perfectly fine question, but could be reworded, since a literal answer ("Yes I do!") isn't very useful. :)

<sub>Full disclosure: [I Am Not Perfect](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5936/do-you-take-pictures-or-make-pictures). :)</sub>

Comment: I like your disclosure, more people should be doing that.

Answer (score 3):

This really, truly seems covered by

> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”

I am open to rewording it slightly, but it feels plenty covered to me.

Comment: Why not add @mattdm's wording? I think the additional wording will go a long way towards clarifying it.

Comment: When one is looking quickly at the FAQ, that point seems addressed at discouraging providing a guess at the answer along with the question, rather than the issue of survey-type questions.

Comment: @matt I think the distinction is awfully subtle. Can you propose an edit to the existing copy rather than adding more?